# Fragments and backstage sometimes get messed up

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-backstack, fragmentmanager

I have an activity with a container for fragments and a NavigationDrawer. If I select an item in the drawer, I call `updatePage(index)`.

I also call `updatePage(0)` if I create the activity and the `savedInstanceState == null` to init my activity.

One fragment has a sub fragment and therefor it just replaces itself by the subfragment and adds the subfragment to the backstack, so that the user can navigate back to the previous fragment. In this fragment I call following code directly:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Event event = (Event)view.getTag();

    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    GamesFragment f = new GamesFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(GamesFragment.KEY_EVENT, event);
    f.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, f, f.getClass().getName())
            .addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

**Why does sometimes the removing of the old fragment not work? I get overlaying fragments, but only sometimes.**

My activities `updatePage` function looks like following:

```
private void updatePage(int drawerSelection)
{
    mDrawer.closeDrawer();

    Fragment f = null;
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    switch (drawerSelection)
    {
        case 0:
            f = fm.findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.class.getName());
            if (f == null)
                f = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            f = fm.findFragmentByTag(EventFragment.class.getName());
            if (f == null)
                f = new EventFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (f != null && !f.isAdded())
    {
        // SOLUTION:
        // Backstack clearen
        // fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, f, f.getClass().getName());
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw such situation few times and I bet that it can happen after replacing with addToBackStack. Easiest fix is to add background to fragment layout. From android doc:

> Note: When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts. If you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced.

This view is not redrawed entirely just overdrawed and if second fragment doesn't has background or view container redraw you will get effect as described. That's my theory :>. Sometimes Android documentation is not as clear as we would like it to be.

Comment: Actually, I now understand why this happens... Will post a short solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem is following use case:

Going to the `EventFragment` from the `GameFragment` pushes the "remove(EventFragment).add(GameFragment)" transaction to the backstack. If I now press the back button, this transaction will be undone and everything is fine. The backstack is empty again and everything works. BUT, if I don't press the back button, but change to another fragment through the menu, the backstack does still have the above mentioned transaction. Pressing back will now try to undo this transaction... It will just readd the EventFragment before the code in my menu click handler adds the fragment from the menu... This is how it could happen...

Easy solution, if I only want one backstack for every menu entry and want to delete the backstack, if I select another area of my app in the menu is, to clear the backstack before I go to another area through the menu...

**So adding ' fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);' before replacing the the current fragment will solve the problem (I added this solution as a comment to my main post)**